# Authentication problem with connecting to mongodb Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What I want to accomplish is probably the simplest thing ever. I just want to connect to mongodb atlas free tier M0 in nodejs using mongodb driver. I already have created a free account and cluster.

Here is my simple code:

```
const mongoclient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const URI = 'mongodb+srv://mohammed:mypassword@lebran-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true';

mongoclient.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('mongodb connected');
    db = client.db('mern');
})
```

Here is what happens when I run the file:

```
Mohammeds-MacBook-Pro:mern ahmed$ node server.js
/Users/ahmed/Projects/mern/server.js:13
    if(err) throw err;
            ^

Error: queryTxt ESERVFAIL lebran-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:199:19)
```

I also tried mongo shell with the following command:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://lebran-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net/mern" --username mohammed
```

here is the output I get:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://lebran-shard-00-00-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,lebran-shard-00-01-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,lebran-shard-00-02-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017/mern?gssapiServiceName=mongodb&ssl=true
2019-02-20T22:48:57.232+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I am sure I enter my password right. I have changed several ones and none of them work. I have my IP listed as white list. I also have an admin account. All the prerequisites I can think of.

I am able to connect to the local server but not to the Atlas. This really beginning to drive me crazy.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

**UPDATE:
I just deployed my app to heroku and you know what? It connects!! I could not get it to connect using my computer though. So probably it has to do something with my location or my connection, probably the location.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct database name and credentials, In node.js you are using test db while on shell you are trying to connect to mern db.

Comment: I tried `mongodb+srv://mohammed:asdf@lebran-0qf7m.gcp.mongodb.net/mern` as a URI, but to no avail. I am sure I type in my password right. Do you think it might have something to do with. TSL or SSL?

Comment: using srv automatically turns on ssl, check with your server configuration

Comment: facing the same issue on localhost. Any breakthrough?